# Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3

Tags: android, flutter, github, bitbucket

i installed last versions of android and flutter, after cloning project from github repository getting this error

Launching lib\main.dart on BKK LX2 in debug mode...

```
lib\main.dart
AILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this error apper only while cloning any project from github and bitbucket, if create new project working fine.

build.gradel file

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

app\build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1.4'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.eightworx.excrm"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        s true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0' 
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7' 
}
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (4 days ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\8X\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\8X\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • BKK LX2 (mobile) • BBPBB19130206058 • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
```

also there is a issues in flutter doctor result, working fine with is issues in android studio and visual studio code.

thank you for helping me.

Comment: Are you using any VPN? What is your DNS? (I suggest using googles 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). Is your project using any custom VPN, are your permissions working? When you copied, are you using SSH, or HTTPS?

Comment: i don't use any VPN or custome VPN in my project, already used googles 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and also have the same error.

Comment: If the version is not mandatory, can you try to get the latest (using `:+`) and see if it at least starts a download, once you have a cached version, you can rollback to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install flutter and dart first go to android studio then configuration choose update
Update your version and then go to configuration agian choose plugins search for flutter ,dart  and install them and restart